# Background color not restored for dynamically generated controls (ASP.NET)

Tags: css, asp.net, html-table, background-color, dynamic-controls

I am generating a `<TABLE>` dynamically in ASP.net. Based on certain events, I need to highlight (via background color) the specific cell `<TD>` in question and de-highlight any previously selected cell.

Sadly, after each event, the previously selected cells are still highlighted. I've written a small piece of code that replicates my problem with 2 buttons that simulate instances of two events.

Creation of Table ...

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table tbl = new Table();
        this.Controls.Add(tbl);

        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        tbl.Controls.Add(row);

        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        cell1.ID = "cell1";
        cell1.Text = "CELL 1";

        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell2.Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        cell2.ID = "cell2";
        cell2.Text = "CELL 2";

        row.Controls.Add(cell1);
        row.Controls.Add(cell2);
    }
```

I highlight the first cell during this event

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell ctr1 = (TableCell)this.FindControl("cell1");
        ctr1.Style.Add("background-color", "yellow");
    }
```

I highlight the second cell during this event. The first cell should no longer be highlighted as I have just recreated this table on postback !

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell ctr2 = (TableCell)this.FindControl("cell2");
        ctr2.Style.Add("background-color", "yellow");
    }
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated ! An alternate approach to achieve the desired effect would be welcome too !

Comment: in button2.click you are asking to find the "cell2" control, and in button 1 the "cell1" control. Check that

Comment: @Eric, thanks ! explicitly setting the color does solve the problem here, but if I remove this explicit code, the previous highlight remains.

Comment: Of course it remains, it won't change it color until you command it.

Comment: Ohh I see the issue now. after submiting the color remains? That's because of cached memory :)

Comment: Set it manually again or : http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-clear-your-ASP-NET-applications-Cache.aspx

Comment: @Eric, oh ! so i need to clear the browser cache via asp.net ?

Comment: Tried the cache removal code by calling it in Page_Init() for each call, but the problem still remains :-?

Comment: do you mind if you set it manually? Sometimes the easier way it's the best one lol

Comment: I think I will have to for now :) Only problem being the actual code has a lot of cells and manually searching and setting each one of them doesn't seem too elegant. But at least it works !

Comment: are you using jquery ? I can provide a solution if so

Comment: unfortunately I am using plain old asp.net !

Comment: @Eric, it was a problem with viewstate. Thanks for pointing out the typo in the old code. Correcting it made me realize that the old cell has the background color set to yellow on the "server" side - which obviously meant someone was restoring it ! Phew !

Comment: nvm preets, it was my pleasure, it kept me entretained ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewState had come back to haunt me!

When creating the dynamic controls setting `EnableViewState = false` solves the problems.

Here, ASP.net was restoring the background color from ViewState and in most cases this is the behavior you want and expect for your dynamically generated controls !